# how veticaly move div bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My code:

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm">
                <h1 class="status">Status:</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container2 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
                <span class="open"><?php include 'opent-stengt.php'?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container3 row col-md-9">
            <p class="info"><?php include 'status.php'?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="container4 row col">
            <span class="buttonfix mt-4"><a class="button1">Sist oppdatert:<?php include 'time.php'?></a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to move the text down, maybe about 16% on desktop. i also want it to look gott on mobile etc. How can I do this? this is my codepen: https://codepen.io/andve04/pen/MWwJbpb
There is also a bug were the "open" covers the "status" chen minimizing the window? How can i fix this.

Any help is greatly appresicated!

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what actually you want i mean waht does these two sentence means `I am trying to move the text down` and `bug were the "open" covers the "status"`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly look at below code and link if it's your expected requirement:

```
<div class="container w3-animate-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container1 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm">
            <h1 class="status">Status:</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container2 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
            <div class="open">OPEN</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="container3 row col-md-9">
        <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container4 row col">
        <span class="buttonfix mt-4"><a class="button1">Last updated:<?php include 'time.php'?></a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

URL: https://codepen.io/andve04/pen/MWwJbpb

Comment: I want to have "status:" and "open" side by side until you reach the point where having them under each other is more natural. In your example you just have to rows, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want both of then side by side then wrap both the `row`s into one `div` and then try.

Answer (score 0):

You should use media-queries, to make the text smaller. Here is an example of all needed media-queries.

```
/**
 * XL
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}

/**
 * LG
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .open {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

/**
 * MD
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

}

/**
 * SM
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .open {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}

/**
 * XS
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 575px) {

}
```

You can move the Text down with something like:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 16vh;
}
```

Comment: yes, but i still get a bug. When I get under 1199px the green and red container in the codepen overlaps eachother. there is also some space on the left of the `opne`, when on mobile